# Implementing 2D vector in Rust

Tags: rust

```rust
// GMatrix is the structure that will implement the matrix
pub struct GMatrix {
    pub vec_list: Vec<String>,
    pub matrix: Vec<Vec<i32>>,
}

impl GMatrix {
    pub fn new() -> GMatrix {
        let v: Vec<Vec<i32>> = Vec::new();
        GMatrix {
            vec_list: vec![],
            matrix: v,
        }
    }

    // insert_vertex inserts into the vertex
    pub fn insert_vertex(&mut self, vertex_name: &str) -> Result<(), String> {
        if self.vec_list.iter().any(|i| i == vertex_name) {
            return Err(format!("Vector already present"));
        }
        self.vec_list.push(vertex_name.to_string());
        let mut v: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
        self.matrix.append(&v);
        self.update_vector();
        Ok(())
    }

    /// update_vector adds another row when another vector is added
    /// will be called inside insert_vector function, so no need to
    /// be public
    fn update_vector(&mut self) {
        for i in 0..self.vec_list.len() - 1 {
            if self.matrix[i].len() < self.vec_list.len() {
                self.matrix[i].push(-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying I guess the error is in line 23 where I try to append another vector. The compiler throws the error.

```
   |
23 |         self.matrix.append(&v);
   |                            ^^ types differ in mutability
   |
   = note: expected mutable reference `&mut Vec<Vec<i32>>`
                      found reference `&Vec<i32>`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I thought I created a vector in `insert_vertex` that is mutable, and yet I try to append it to another vector I get an error.

Comment: `& T` and `&mut T` are different kinds of references, and have no relation to `mut` as variable mutability modifier.

Comment: @IvanC: "*have no relation*" is not entirely correct, as you can't create `&mut` reference to a variable unless it is declared with the `mut` modifier.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want [`push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push) instead of `append`.